# INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... produces defective table, where CREATE TABLE ... SELECT

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I am working on processing a large set of GTFS data and I create an additional table from existing data. For this I use the following query.

```
INSERT INTO connections
(SELECT
    stop_timesD.departure_time,
    stop_timesD.stop_sequence AS stop_sequence_departure,
    stop_timesD.stop_id AS stop_id_departure,
    trips.trip_id,
    trips.direction_id,
    stop_timesA.arrival_time, 
    stop_timesA.stop_sequence AS stop_sequence_arrival, 
    stop_timesA.stop_id AS stop_id_arrival 
FROM trips 
INNER JOIN stop_times AS stop_timesD ON trips.trip_id = stop_timesD.trip_id 
INNER JOIN stop_times AS stop_timesA ON trips.trip_id = stop_timesA.trip_id 
INNER JOIN calendar_dates ON trips.service_id = calendar_dates.service_id 
WHERE calendar_dates.date = '20190302' AND stop_timesD.stop_sequence < stop_timesA.stop_sequence);
```

Now this produces the dataset that I require properly. However, the table it is inserted into does not seem to be query-able since every query (i.e. SELECT * FROM connections;) does not return any data. Furthermore the server keeps using a lot of CPU power after the query has finished and produces a large value for 'free data' (I suspect it is either cleaning up or indexing).

Using a modified query that creates the new table (CREATE TABLE connections SELECT ...) does produce the desired result, even though there is no difference in table layout.

Comment: Isn't there any transaction involved? `Create` is DDL, which is not in transaction scope. I suppose such a `create from select` is mixed statement that falls also under this approach.

Comment: I just discovered that the python library I am using requires me to commit my changes explicitly. So it is indeed a problem concerning a transaction. Thanks!